# Faster way to insert records into database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parallel.foreach

So I currently have a database table of about 70,000 names.  What I want to do is take 3000 random records from that database and insert them into another table where each name has a row for all the other names.  In other words, the new table should look like this:

```
John, jerry
john, alex
john, sam
jerry, alex
jerry, sam
alex, sam
```

This means that I should be adding summation n rows to the table.  My current strategy is to use two nested for loops to add these rows one at a time and then removing the first name from the list of names to add in order to ensure I dont have a duplicate record with different ordering.

My question is this: is there a faster way to do this, perhaps through parallel for loops or PLINQ or some other option that I a have not mentioned?

Comment: Is your database a relational design?

Comment: Have you heard of [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) operations?

Comment: Cross Join. Don't use loops.

Comment: That isn't n!. 3000! is considerably larger http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3000%21

Comment: good catch on the factorial, my bad @MartinSmith

Comment: By "where each name has a row for all the other names" do you mean all the other names in the sample of 3000 *or* all the 69999 other names?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to figure out the random part

```
select t1.name, t2.name 
from table t1 
join table t2 
on t1.name < t2.name 
order by t1.name, t2.name
```

You need to materialize the newid

```
declare @t table (name varchar(10) primary key);
insert into @t (name) values 
       ('Adam')
     , ('Bob')
     , ('Charlie')
     , ('Den')
     , ('Eric')
     , ('Fred');
declare @top table (name varchar(10) primary key);
insert into @top (name)
select top (4) name from @t order by NEWID();

select * from @top;

select a.name, b.name
from @top a  
join @top b 
  on a.name < b.name  
order by a.name, b.name;
```

Comment: `order by t1.name < t2.name`?

Answer (score 1):

Given a table "Names" with an nvarchar(50) column "Name" with this data:

```
Adam
Bob
Charlie
Den
Eric
Fred
```

This query:

```
-- Work out the fraction we need
DECLARE @frac AS float;
SELECT @frac = CAST(35000 AS float) / 70000;

-- Get roughly that sample size
WITH ts AS (
SELECT Name FROM Names
WHERE @frac >= CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(), Name) & 0x7FFFFFFF AS float) / CAST (0X7FFFFFFF AS int)
)

-- Match each entry in the sample with all the other entries
SELECT x.Name + ', ' + y.Name
FROM ts AS X
CROSS JOIN
Names AS Y
WHERE x.Name <> y.Name
```

produces results of the form

```
Adam, Bob
Adam, Charlie
Adam, Den
Adam, Eric
Adam, Fred
Charlie, Adam
Charlie, Bob
Charlie, Den
Charlie, Eric
Charlie, Fred
Den, Adam
Den, Bob
Den, Charlie
Den, Eric
Den, Fred
```

The results will vary by run; a sample of 3000 out of 70000 will have *approximately* 3000 * 70000 result rows. I used 35000./70000 because the sample size I used was only 6.

If you want only the names from the sample used, change `CROSS JOIN Names AS Y` to `CROSS JOIN ts AS Y`, and there will then be approximately 3000 * 3000 result rows.

Reference: The random sample method was taken from the section "Important" in [Limiting Result Sets by Using TABLESAMPLE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189108(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: You have duplicates.  See sample output from OP.

Comment: @Paparazzi I was rather hoping that the OP's sample output was not exactly what they want and their description of the output is. Let's wait and find out :)

Comment: @Paparazzi Ah, I see what you mean. I have asked the OP for clarification of the other part of the question.

Comment: @Paparazzi If that turns out to be the case, you're welcome to take the random sample code from this answer and pop it into your answer so I can delete this one.

Comment: Cool, I posted another slant

Answer (score 0):

Using a Number table to simulate names.

single query, using a triangular join

```
WITH all_names 
     AS (SELECT n, 
                'NAME_' + Cast(n AS VARCHAR(20)) NAME 
         FROM   number 
         WHERE  n < 70000), 
     rand_names 
     AS (SELECT TOP 3000 * 
         FROM   all_names 
         ORDER  BY Newid()), 
     ordered_names 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    ORDER BY NAME) rw_num, 
                NAME 
         FROM   rand_names) 
SELECT n1.NAME, 
       n2.NAME 
FROM   ordered_names n1 
       INNER JOIN ordered_names n2 
               ON n2.rw_num > n1.rw_num
```

Comment: Did you test this?  CTE is just syntax and can be called multiple times.  I did test.